# Number of integral values of 'a' for which the following is true..

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Question**
>
> If it is given that the equation $$|z|^2-2iz+2c(a+i)=0$$ possesses solution for all $c∈R$, then the number of integral values of 'a' for which it is true is ______.

**Attempt**

Wrote $z=x+iy$ and substituted in the given equation to get $x=c$ as one of the condition. But after that the equation becomes $$y^2+2y+2ac+c^2=0$$. But after this I don't know what to do further.

**Any hints or suggestions?**

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by *integral values*? Do you mean the cases where $a$ is an integer?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve for $y$ and then check for which values of $a$ the solutions are always real, i.e. for which $a$ the discriminant is always positive.

Comment: Actually that is the problem. I am not able to figure out when the discriminant should become positive or negative here in this question. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: So what did you get for the discriminant?

Comment: $D=4-8ac-4c^2$?

Comment: Right, now consider D as a function of $c$ with parameter $a$. What kind of function is it? For which $a$ is it a positive function?

Comment: $D$ is the downward parabola. But how will I know for which 'a' it will be positive?

Comment: It is impossible that $D$ is positive for all $c \in  \mathbb R$. Hence the answer to the original question (number of integral values of $a$) is $0$.

Comment: Oh. Okay I now get it. Thanks for your help. Thanks again.